# "Populus Romanus Quiritium" as vocative?

Tags: syntax, vocative

In *Latin Prose Composition* by John Arbuthnot Nairn (Cambridge UP, 1926; p. 5 of "Versions" section), I find the following as a translation of Shakespeare's "Friends, Romans, countrymen, lend me your ears":

> Populus Romanus Quiritium, amicique et cives mei, benigne me attenteque audiatis.

Is this correct Latin? It seems to me that *Populus Romanus Quiritium* needs to be vocative. But Nairn was an eminent Latinist and I have not so far found any other errors in his book, and it's a little hard to believe that he would have made such an elementary blunder. I've searched for the phrase *Populus Romanus Quiritium* but have not been able to find it used in direct address (while on the other hand Cicero [uses](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/75/1/2301-2308@1#1) *popule Romane* in the vocative).

Is there any possible justification for the nominatives here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has now been answered by Cerberus, though his answer was posted in regard to a different (related) [question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/798/how-to-use-apposition-with-vocative). It seems that there are examples from Livy and Lucan (at least) of the form *populus* being used as a vocative (though *popule* is also attested). So Nairn is justified.

Answer (score 5):

It does indeed look like direct address where the author forgot to use vocative, but it is not the only option.
It is possible to read your sentence this way:

> Listen to me kindly and carefully, as the Roman nation of citizens, as my friends and as my compatriots.

Viewed like this, the use of a nominative without any added words (like the English "as") is perfectly grammatical.
This gives the sentence a different tone, but it says essentially the same thing as the English "Friends, Romans, countrymen, lend me your ears".

Comment: Grammatically you're right of course (and this reading occurred to me too), but taking the phrase as an appositive nominative feels to me like a very unnatural reading. But maybe I'm wrong. I wonder if there any extant Roman orations which begin in a comparable way.

Comment: @TKR, it feels unusual but not unnatural to me, but I don't recall ever seeing such a long apposition before. I don't know if this meaning was intended, but I wanted to record this possibility here. Your last sentence would make a good question.

Comment: But an appositive takes the case of the word it is apposed to—doesn't it?—, which would be an elliptical vocative here, so even in apposition I'd expect a vocative. However, I seem to remember that a "nominativus pro vocativo" was possible...not 100% sure, though, nor in which language this should be possible.

Comment: @Cerberus, my understanding is that an apposition never takes vocative; if it modifies a vocative, it is in nominative. I could be mistaken, though.

Comment: @Cerberus, I made that into a [new question](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/798/79) to ask if my interpretation of such use of vocative is correct.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Hmm interesting. I'm looking forward to the answers...

Comment: @Cerberus, the question got a nice answer. You should see it. :P

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: In the Denison translation, "Amici, Cives, Quirities...", "Quirities" described the Romans in normal, peaceful circumstances. Therefore, why use both "Cives" and "Quirities"? Mark-Antony's speech (Act III, Scene II) was made after the assassination of JC; therefore, the peace of Rome was already dying in front of MA's audience. A second reason to question the use of "Quirities". Of course, I may be mixing-up drama with history, but the Latin is equally interesting.

Comment: @tony I recommend asking a separate question comparing *cives* and *quirites* (not *quirities*). It's a very interesting one, and I'd hate to see a discussion on it buried in the comments of an only tangentially related other question.

Answer (score 2):

(I would leave this as a comment but it's too long, so.)

For what it's worth, there seem to be two translations of *Julius Caesar* into Latin, and both are useless for determining what's "correct" here, since they use plural nouns, which would be the same whether nominative or vocative. One, from 1856, is by [Henry Denison](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/46768/46768-h/46768-h.htm); the relevant lines are rendered:

> Amici, Cives, Quirites, commodate mihi aliquantisper aures vestras: adsum ut efferam Cæsarem, non ut laudem.

The other, from an 1899 issue of *Praeco Latinus* edited by Arcadius Avellanus, is by [C. W. Goodchild](https://books.google.com/books?id=d6pDAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA76&dq=praeco%20latinus%20caesar%20shakespeare&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZvKvKka_MAhWBPD4KHXkFB1QQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=praeco%20latinus%20caesar%20shakespeare&f=false); there they are rendered:

> Romani, amici, cives, auscultate mihi;
>   Venio sepultum non laudatum Cæsarem.

Avellanus was a native Latin speaker, but I don't know the extent to which he futzed with his writers' material in the *Praeco Latinus*. Of Denison and Goodchild, alas, I know nothing, so I'm not in a position to comment on the quality of their translations, but I will say that *commodate mihi aures vestras*, though a literally exact translation of the English, feels far too metaphoric for Latin, which tends to be a very concrete language.